# Calling Java Generic Typed Method from Scala gives a Type mismatch error : Scala

Tags: java, scala, generics, scala-java-interop

This is my very first question down here, so i'll try to make it clear as far as i can. 
Other `error: type mismatch;` questions here are not related to this error.

I have this odd problem with scala/java inter-operability :

Let's suppose we have a Java class

```
public class JavaClass{
  public static <T> T[] toArray(Class<T> t, Collection<T> coll) {
    return null; // return null to make it simple
  }
}
```

And then i have another Scala class i just wanted to wrap this method in :

```
object ScalaClass{
  def toArray[T](t: java.lang.Class[T], coll: java.util.Collection[T]): Array[T] = {
    JavaClass.toArray[T](t, coll);
  }
}
```

compiling the Scala class gives me a very odd error :

```
error: type mismatch;
```

Any idea is appreciated.

EDIT 1:
The full error message is

```
[ERROR] ScalaScala.scala:4002: error: type mismatch;
[INFO]  found   : Array[T]
[INFO]  required: Class[T]
[INFO]  JavaClass.toArray[T](t, coll);
[INFO]                      ^
```

Comment: Can you give the rest of the error message? It should say `found: ...` and `required: ...`. Knowing these types will make it easier to track down the problem.

Comment: thanks just edited to include the full error message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to SO.

This seems to compile, but I am not sure if it works with the real implementation of **JavaClass**, but I am pretty sure it should.

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

object ScalaClass {
  def toArray[T <: AnyRef](coll: java.util.Collection[T])(implicit ct: ClassTag[T]): Array[T] =
    JavaClass.toArray[T](ct.runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[T]], coll)
}
```

To call it from **Scala** you just need to pass the java collection, it would get the correct class from the type, like this:

```
val col: java.util.Collection[String] = ???

val array: Array[String] = ScalaClass.toArray(col)
```

---

### Edit

If you want to preserve the original signature, you have to do this:

```
object ScalaClass {
  def toArray[T <: AnyRef](t: java.lang.Class[T], coll: java.util.Collection[T]): Array[T] =
    JavaClass.toArray[T](t, coll)
}
```

Which you can use like this:

```
val col: java.util.Collection[String] = ???

val array: Array[String] = ScalaClass.toArray(classOf[String], col)
```

---

In both cases the trick is the `<: AnyRef` **type bound**.
IMHO, the first version is more *ergonomic* to be used on idiomatic Scala code.

Comment: Thanks but this does change the scala method signature to include a single param and implicitly deduce the second.

Comment: @thevpc well I just did that to make the method more ergonomic to use. It is strange to manually pass an instance of the **Class** class in Scala. But it could be changed if you need to.